# Add/merge columns from 3+ different CSV files into one file in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I'm trying to merge 3 files into a new one with the information from all 3.

The structure would be

```
file1.csv

Column1   Column2
numbers   letters
1233      aabbcc
```

All 3 files have the same columns structure I want to combine them like this

```
combined.csv
Column1   Column2  Column3   Column4  Column5   Column6
numbers   letters  numbers   letters  numbers   letters 
1233      aabbcc   1233      aabbcc   1233      aabbcc
```

How would i go about this with shell scripting?
Thanks

Comment: Is the delimiter tab? Can fields contain quoted tabs? Are the column names unique?

Comment: If yes, no, and yes: `paste file[123].csv >combined.csv`

Comment: It's yes, no and no. Names are the same for all columns. Tried paste but columns kinda merged together.

Comment: do your files have dos line endings?

Comment: No, i'm using this to escape separate the values
` | sed "s/'/\'/;s/\t/\",\"/g;s/^/\"/;s/$/\"/;s/\n//g" `